# INDIRECT function to specify external reference file

Tags: excel

I am using this formula to find the row number of the last valid entry in a sheet:

=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW([A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A))*([A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A<>"")))

I have a list with several values, including "A17U.SI.csv" and "A17U.SI". Is it possible to reference those with the INDIRECT function?

Also, the reference A:A should not become a string (& A:A), it should remain dynamic so I can drag it to other columns.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You can use INDIRECT if those files are open.  You cannot if the external workbooks are closed.  Related to: http://superuser.com/questions/535871/

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The values "A17U.SI.csv" and "A17U.SI" are stored in a table in the same workbook. The referenced csv files are open. I am unclear about the syntax of the SUMPRODUCT formula it if is to include INDIRECT.

Comment: Then the answer is likely yes.  Are you having a specific problem with `INDIRECT`?

Comment: Yes. The question is how I should write the formula 

=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW([A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A))*([A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A<>"")))

using INDIRECT when the values "A17U.SI.csv" and "A17U.SI" are located in A3 and B3, respectively.

Comment: The `INDIRECT` formula is pretty straightforward.  Here is a good workup of examples including your case of referencing another workbook.  http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html

Comment: indirect is for building cell references using a string... is that what you want?

Comment: The list with the filenames will be updated periodically, and I want to avoid hardcoding them into the formula. I understand the simple examples with a range between A and B, but with nested formulas I can't seem to wrap my head around the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(INDIRECT("'[" & A3 & "]" & B3 & "'!" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","") & ":" &  SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",""))))*(INDIRECT("'[" & A3 & "]" & B3 & "'!"  & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","") &":" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","") )<>"")))
```

Essentially, you are just needing to make your existing formula dynamic via the `INDIRECT` function. When using it, you just need to make sure you use the single quotes, brackets, and exclamation point to make the syntax valid. Your goal is simply to reproduce what you had hard-coded in there in your original formula.

The tricky part to your question was actually the need for a dynamic range reference, which makes the formula much uglier because we keep having to include this to get the letters for the range in a way that will be dynamically update:

```
SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")
```

For example, if you put the above formula on its own in any cell in the A column, it will evaluate to "A". If you could put that in its own cell in the column, then you could simply reference that cell and it would make the formula a bit easier to read. For example, if we put `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")` in cell `A1`, then we could write:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(INDIRECT("'[" & A3 & "]" & B3 & "'!" & A1 & ":" &  A1)))*(INDIRECT("'[" & A3 & "]" & B3 & "'!"  & A1 &":" & A1 )<>"")))
```

You asked about the syntax when using `INDIRECT` in `SUMPRODUCT`. By the time `SUMPRODUCT` is involved, if we wrote the `INDIRECT` part right, it shouldn't be any different syntax than what you already had.